# Unable to boot with dracut and luks: '/dev/resume' : file exists

Tags: boot, lvm, gentoo, luks, initramfs

I am installing gentoo and have performed my first reboot after configuration and installation within my chroot environment. I am using LUKS and LVM to manage encryption of my drives. I am encrypting my swap partition (/dev/sda2) and my usr partition (/dev/ssdvg/usr).

Problem is after booting and entering my passphrase to unlock my swap partition dracut throws the following error:

```
dracut-initqueue[498]: In: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/resume': File exists
```

After this the boot process stops and I am thrown to a dracut console.

Comment: Does [this link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/46708/cant-boot-dracut-initqueue303-failed-to-create-link/) help?

Comment: It turns out that, dracut just throws that warning and I can only assume its throwing that since the device is already created in the initramfs that dracut creates. 

I had assumed this was the source of my failure to boot since it was the only error being thrown. Upon further investigation I found that the source of the error was my dracut configuration that was incorrect. A device that was not a lvm was set in the configuration as one.

@eyoung100 That link didn't help but i realised while going through that solution that I had not fully configured dracut correctly.